# Has anyone dig into the data format of the mac sticky notes database?

Tags: macos, dataformat

It's located under /Users/username/Library/StickiesDatabase.

I've tried to work on it. It seems to be an out-dated un-keyed Archive file, which nowadays are keyed. NSCoder will do the work, however I can't figure out the Document class organization.

Anyone with any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running [`class-dump`](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) on the Stickies application gave me the following interface, among others:

```
@interface Document : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
    int mWindowColor;
    int mWindowFlags;
    struct CGRect mWindowFrame;
    NSData *mRTFDData;
    NSDate *mCreationDate;
    NSDate *mModificationDate;
}
```

That looks like it's probably the class you're after!

Comment: Wow, good job, I'm also curious about the writing order of these data, and what's inside mRTFData?

Comment: Order should be as specified in that interface. `mRTFDData` is probably some sort of serialized RTF string.

Comment: Yes, actually the order is mRTFData, mWindowFlags, mWindowFrame, mWindowColor, then mCreationDate and mModificationDate. I still need some work on the RTFData. lol